# How to fix issue with @URL.Action in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm jumping to asp.net core. I have experience working with MVC framework.

When i set a URL.Action("Index", "Home") in a javascript variable the result is: "/Home/Index/" in mvc 4,

but in ASP.NET Core i try to do exactly the same, but what i only get is a slash printed "/"

what's wrong? I have read other questions, but no one can give a right answer.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" id="urlIndex" />
```

result:

```
<input type="hidden" value="/" id="urlIndex" />
```

Comment: Because your matching your 'Default' route which defaults to to `Index` method of `HomeController` (and you would get exactly the same result if you matched the Default route in previous versions of mvc). Note there is nothing to _fix_ - the url generated is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stephen Muecke points out, this is by design.

If you need to generate `/Home/Index` by `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")`, try to add `Route` on `/Home/Index` for a workaround.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route("/")]
    [Route("/Home/Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```